# Why jQuery ajax added same cookie in my request header multiple times?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, cookies, asp.net-web-api

I have been trapped in this on for many hours, wondering if you have could help me out or provide me some suggestion?

Long story short,
I have a asp.net web api application, In one of my page, I am trying to load some data from web api and add them into few dropdown lists.
Anyway, I use jQuery ajax when the page loads

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    //Fires when page loads
    LoadMachines();
    LoadMachieGroups();
    LoadPrinterServer();
    LoadSavePreference();
});
```

Each of the functions does the similar job, for example

```
 function LoadMachieGroups() {
        console.log("Before group " + document.cookie);
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            url: "/api/Machine/MachineGroups",
            //data: "{}",
            success: function (response) {
                OnMachinesGroupLoadSuccess(response);
            }
        });

        console.log("after group " + document.cookie);
    }
```

The issue is that, we the code runs to the third (LoadPrinterServer) and fourth function (LoadSavePreference).  The request header passed the same cookies (DoxMachineId) with different values three times. (Please see the picture), which then cause the trouble in my c# code to find the correct result.

My questions are:
1.) Why could same cookie added in the header multiple times? Is this because of multiple ajax calls?
2.) How to solve the problem? For example: remove the cookies?

Thanks guys in advanced.

[image]

Comment: what is the path assigned to those cookies

Comment: @ArunPJohny  good question! I set up the cookies in webapi code,  response.Headers.AddCookies(EnumerableEx.Return(machineCookie));

Answer (score 0):

Since I stumbled over the same (or pretty similar) problem and could not find a solution elsewhere, here comes my self-found-after-severe-frustration-solution:

When I sent the `set-cookie` header to the client, I missed to set its `path` argument to `/` (the root) on the server side. The client interpreted this as to set the path of the cookie to the parent of the leaf of its current target-path. In my case, that meant `/api` (since it has been an ajax-call to `/api/create`).

So, the client ended up with storing one instance of the cookie per path (in my case, for each api-call, there was an instance of the cookie stored at the client-side, as well as one cookie for the root-path that has been set by loading resources).

Whenever the client sent a request to the server later on, it attached all of the cookie-instances (with their respective values) to this request that matched the current target-path (again, in my case, whenever the client requested `/api/create` it attached the cookie-instance of the path `/` as well as the instance of the path `/api` which means the same cookie with two different values).

Comment: (I should have paid more attention to the comment of Arun above in the first place.)